# Django on Google app engine cannot serve media files

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I deployed a Django web app on Google app engine flex env, and I could upload files to this app, but the `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` are not set to Google cloud storage for now, so uploaded files should be stored on local disk.

The problem is, when I open the app website, some uploaded images cannot load successfully, with error saying

```
GET https://app-name.ew.r.appspot.com/media/images/icon_TPUrf8a.jpg 404
```

and strangely, even the same image could some time load and then sometime cannot load, very random.

Could anyone please tell why it sometimes ok and sometime not, and what's the best way to fix it?

Comment: Did you remember to set your permissions 'User: AllUsers` for these files?  Look in your GCS console

Comment: @GAEfan, I wonder why I need to set GCS for this? Since my MEDIA_URL/MEDIA_ROOT is not configured to be on GCS bucket, it should be on local disk, right?

Comment: Sorry, your mentioning GCS confused me.  Can you update the question with your static file handlers from app.yaml?

Comment: @GAEfan, I don't have handlers at all in app.yaml.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell the app where to look for your static files.  This is best done in `app.yaml`:

```
handlers:  
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/

- url: .*
  script: auto
```

Comment: He asked about media files, not static files.